# xpath find a div that contains a certain text and get next span

Tags: html, xpath

What I have now: `div[2]/span[2]`

What I would like to have: `div[text()[contains(., 'text2')]]/span[2]`

HTML:

```
<div class="line"><span class="name">text1:</span>
    <span class="value">1</span></div>
<div class="line"><span class="name">text2:</span>
    <span class="value">2</span></div>
```

I would like to get access to the second span element from a div that contains my text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way :

```
div[contains(.,'text2')]/span[2]
```

I personally prefer to filter target span by `class` attribute value instead of using position index `2` :

```
div[contains(.,'text2')]/span[@class='value']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And the filtering more than welcomed!